# WordPress Issue: Intermittent Internal Service Error and white flash on page load

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I've looked through the past questions but didn't find an answer to my particular issue so I thought I'd see what I can find out here. I am having an Internal Server Error for a WordPress site I am developing (http://www.pup-grass.com). The error comes up intermittently, with no real logic that I can see, and usually goes away if you refresh the page after getting the internal server error window. The site has also begun to flash a white screen before each page load creating an annoying white flash as you move around the site.

I've tried to resolve the issue by: replacing the .htaccess file and creating a new one; checking file permissions; upping the php memory limits, checking the plug-ins one at a time; and by ultimately replacing the wp-admin and wp-includes folder with new ones from a WordPress download. I am not sure what more I can do. Does anybody have any suggestions?

Thanks,

Sam

Comment: You mention that you looked for solution to your "particular issue", yet for us you only sketch a very vague description. You need to be much more precise for us to be able to help. First thing to add to the question: the entries you have in your http servers error log file.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how to find that file. Could you point me in the correct direction?

Comment: In your http servers host configuration there are typically two log files configured: access and error log. You are looking for the `ErrorLog` directive, the typical location of such log file is something like `/var/log/apache2/error.log` or inside some host specific folder at that location.

Comment: Wow. If I have the correct file, its a long one. Here's the most recent entries.

Comment: 20150921T144442: www.pup-grass.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in /hermes/bosoraweb126/b1217/ipg.pupgearcorporation/pupgrasswp/wp-content/plugins/fusion-core/admin/page-builder/classes/class-fa-iterator.php on line 102

20150921T144536: www.pup-grass.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 71 bytes) in /hermes/bosoraweb126/b1217/ipg.pupgearcorporation/pupgrasswp/wp-

Comment: Not sure if that's helpful, is there a way that I can send the whole file?

Comment: It is only the last entries that are of interest. And they already tell you what the issue is you are looking for. A general hint: you _cannot_ develop in php in a web environment without monitoring that error log file. That would be like flying in a narrow cave with eyes closed. Not a good idea...

Comment: Thanks. As you might have ascertained I'm not a php developer. So this helps. Though, I'm not sure what to do with the file...Will adding more memory to the wp-config file sovle this?

Comment: You hit a configured limit of the php engine. The reason for that limit simply is robustness against scripts that run wild. You can raise that limit in your `php.ini` file, but that will only push the issue further. The real question is why your scripts require such an amount of memory. Those are 65MB of memory for a single script execution! You want to tackle that issue instead. Most likely some recursive algorithm copying some array again and again or similar.